# how dynamically generate number of y axis in plotly dash

Tags: plotly-dash

I learned how to make multiple y axis by hardcoding (see blow).
However, I am not sure if its possible to make this dynamic. For example, if the user have 3 plots, instead of hard code 3 dictionary in the "fig.update_layout()", is there a way do this more dynamically? because if the user has 50 plots, its not practical to hardcode 50 dictionary in the fig.update_layout() to make 50 y axis.

Thanks!

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6], name="yaxis data"))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[40, 50, 60], name="yaxis2 data", yaxis="y2"))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[4, 5, 6], y=[1000, 2000, 3000], name="yaxis3 data", yaxis="y3")
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[3, 4, 5], y=[400, 500, 600], name="yaxis4 data", yaxis="y4")
)

# how to dynamically generate axis instead of hard coding?
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(domain=[0.25, 0.75]),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="yaxis title",
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        title="yaxis2 title",
        overlaying="y",
        side="right",
    ),
    yaxis3=dict(title="yaxis3 title", anchor="free", overlaying="y", autoshift=True),
    yaxis4=dict(
        title="yaxis4 title",
        anchor="free",
        overlaying="y",
        autoshift=True,
    ),
)

fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Shifting y-axes with autoshift",
)

fig.show()
```